# React pagination: Limit number of pages shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm hoping someone can help :)

I have created a page, using react, where i can load data from an API and paginate the data.

I would like to limit the number of pages shown, but the way i have coded it is not exactly what i was after. What i'm trying to do is show 10 pages at a time (like this tutorial (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/03/14/react-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google).

What i managed to do is limit the number of pages, but the amount of pages to the right keeps increasing, so instead of the pages shown being consistent, it goes from

[First] [<<] **[1]** [2] [>>] [Last]

[First] [<<] [1] **[2]** [3] [>>] [Last]

[First] [<<] [1] [2] **[3]** [4] [>>] [Last]

[First] [<<] [2] [3] **[4]** [>>] [Last]

I've created a demo (https://codesandbox.io/s/x6l4q), using the regres.in API. Unfortunately it doesn't have a lot of records to demonstrate my issue, but hopefully it will give you an idea of what is happening.

Any pointers, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think i've made some progress - added in a startIndex & endIndex which now let's me control the number of pages shown (new code in codesandbox). Just need to get the pages to move position when I hit the next/prev buttons now.

Comment: Got the Next/Prev buttons working as they should. First/Last buttons no longer work though. I've updated sandbox with the latest code. Any help, much appreciated :)